# team build target not executed

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have a tfs 2008 build that I need to add WiX compliation to.

Currently the build executes and compiles and copies all output to a drops location in the following target

```
<Target Name="AfterCompile"> .... </Target>
```

I have added another target directly below it that looks like the following

```
<UsingTask TaskName="HeatDirectory" AssemblyFile="$(WixTasksPath)" />

<Target Name="BuildMsi" DependsOnTargets="AfterCompile">
  <Message Text="Start harvesting Website files for Wix compliation" />
  <HeatDirectory
                ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)"
                Directory="$(DropLocation)\Latest\x86\Release\_PublishedWebsites\IFMA.MasterPlan.Web"
                GenerateGuidsNow="yes"
                ComponentGroupName="Web"
                OutputFile="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Setup\Product\Fragments\wwwfiles.wxs"
                SuppressFragments="yes"
                DirectoryRefId="WebRoot"
                KeepEmptyDirectories="yes"
                PreprocessorVariable="var.WebRoot"
                SuppressRegistry="yes"
                SuppressRootDirectory="yes"
                SuppressCom="yes"
                   />

  <Message Text="Finished harvesting Website files for Wix compliation" />

</Target>
```

The BuildMsi target is never executed but the AfterCompile one definitly is.

The BuildMsi isn't listed in the default build targets
    
but I thought that since it has a dependency on AfterCompile it would be executed after it.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm not sure if the heat task is correct but I don't actually care more worried about getting the target to execute and then I can worry about getting the heat task to work

Comment: Daniel - I added some information about target injection which you probably can use in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DependsOnTargets lists the targets that must be executed before your target can run, it does not force your target to run after the list of targets run.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t50z2hka(v=VS.90).aspx

If you're using MSBuild 4.0, [AfterTargets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t50z2hka%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) attribute is what you need:

> AfterTargets: Optional attribute.
>
> A semicolon-separated list of target
>   names. When specified, indicates that
>   this target should run after the
>   specified target or targets.  This
>   lets the project author extend an
>   existing set of targets without
>   modifying them directly.

Alternatively you can use target injection, which basically is overriding the CompileDependsOn property in your .proj file to include your target at the end. You need to declare this property after the imports of the common target files to ensure it is the last definition of the property.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <CompileDependsOn>
        $(CompileDependsOn);
        MyCustomTarget
    </CompileDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

See ["How to extend the visual studio build process"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724.aspx) for more details.